# Show date of next thursday

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I use the following code to display the date of every next thursday.

Now I got the following problem: today is thursday, but I don't want to show the date of the next week until the current day is over. How is that possible?

Every thursday we have duty from 7pm to 10pm. Therefore I need to display todays date for example. After 10pm I can display the date of the next thursday (for example 30.11.)

Current code:

```
 $timestmp = strtotime('next thursday');
 setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
 $next = strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y', $timestmp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a simple `if condition` to check if today is Thursday, print today's date. Else, print next Thursday

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");

if (date('l') == 'Thursday') {
    $thu = strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y');
} else {
    $timestmp = strtotime('next thursday');
    $thu = strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y', $timestmp);
}

echo $thu;
```

Answer (score 1):

> if(date('l') == 'Thursday') {
>   echo 'Today is Thursday! Whola!'
>   }
>   else {
>   $timestmp = strtotime('next thursday');
>    setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");
>   $next = strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y', $timestmp);
>   }

Answer (score 0):

So you want show today this thursday?
Then pass to strtotime, yesterday's timestamp. Like that

```
 $timestmp = strtotime('next thursday', strtotime('-1 day'));
```

Then it will seek for next thursday from yesterday, which is today.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly what I want. I manage the website from my local volunteer fire department. Every thursday we have duty from 7pm to 10pm. Therefore I need to display todays date for example. After 10pm I can display the date of the next thursday (for example 30.11.)

Answer (score 0):

The following code grabs the next thursday if its sunday, monday, tuesday or wednesday. It grabs the last thursday if it's firday or saturday. And it will grab the current day if it's thursday today.

```
$now = new DateTime();
if ($now->format('w') < 4) {
    $now->modify('next thursday')
} elseif ($now->format('w') > 4) {
    $now->modify('last thursday')
}

echo $now->format('Y-m-d');
```